# Change default_retry_delay for a celery task at runtime?

Tags: python, celery

Is there a way to modify the retry delay for celery tasks at runtime? Or is there a global config value that can be changed to override the 180s default value?

I have set up tasks with exponential back-off (as described here: [Retry Celery tasks with exponential back off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731435/retry-celery-tasks-with-exponential-back-off)) but I want to override this value when integration testing.

The reason is that I often end up triggering the 180s default value if exceptions are raised within an exception handler, which seems to bypass and ignore the countdown argument.

```
class BaseTask(celery.Task):
    def on_retry(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        """Log the exceptions at retry."""
        logger.exception(exc)
        logger.warning('Retry: {}.'.format(self.request))
        super().on_retry(exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        """Log the exceptions on failure."""
        logger.exception(exc)
        logger.error('Failure: {}.'.format(self.request))
        super().on_failure(exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)

    @property
    def backoff_countdown(self):
        return int(random.uniform(2, 4) ** self.request.retries)

@celery.task(bind=True, base=BaseTask)
def process(self, data):
    try:
        return some_task(data)
    except Exception as exc:
        raise self.retry(exc=exc, coundown=self.backoff_countdown)
```

Regardless of what I set for `self.backoff_countdown` (even just returning `1`) I end up with tasks being retried in `180s`, which makes it really hard to run integration tests with reasonable timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to document http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#using-a-custom-retry-delay, can set default_retry_delay or set the countdown value.

```
@celery.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=30 * 60) # retry in 30 minutes.
def process(self, data):
    try:
        return some_task(data)
    except Exception as exc:
        # Retry in 5 minutes
        raise self.retry(exc=exc, countdown=5 * 60)
```

Comment: Yes, I know of that setting but it's not something I can change at runtime - at least not that I can see.

Maybe I'm phrasing this badly. I'm ok with the 3min normal retry delay and I don't want to change that in the source. However, I do want to override that value when I run this same source in a docker image by some configuration setting that I can inject or by some instrumentation that I add to my tests.

Comment: How about override the retry method of Task object?

Comment: This code is running in a docker container. The best I can do is inject config files or set env variables. I guess I could try to inject a value for `@celery.task(... default_retry_delay=...)` via an env variable but that seems awfully convoluted and is not something I'd like to ship.

Comment: From your code, i don't see your method is override the `default_retry_delay` value, you can try to override the retry method of Task object with your countdown parameter.

Comment: I think a better description of my problem would be: Given the tasks are defined as shown and assuming that I cannot change them, how could I adjust `default_retry_delay` from the 'outside' to achieve the same effect as via the `@celery.task` decorator.